# SSH into EC2 and run psql queries using terraform

Tags: terraform, psql, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-aurora

I am writing terraform code to deploy Aurora Clusters and then using local_exec to run some sql queries to create DB/Users/Extensions on the Writer Instance. Something like this

main.tf:

```
resource "null_resource" "execute_queries" {

  provisioner "local-exec" {
     command = pg_queries.sh.tpl", {
       dbname = var.xxxx
       username = var.xxxx
        })

      environment = {
          PGHOST        = xxxx
          PGDATABASE    = xxxx
          PGUSER        = xxxx
          PGPASSWORD    = xxxx
          DBPORT        = xxxx
                    }
  }
```

The code for pg_queries.sh.tpl is something like:

```
#!/bin/bash


echo "Creating DB and Users. Please wait ...."

psql << EOF

Create USER XXXX;
Create Database XXXXXXX;
..
..
..
EOF
```

Now we run the terraform code (terraform apply) from our local systems and It works fine for our testing and staging environment however for Prod, we restrict DB connections from EC2 instances in the same VPC ONLY due to which the psql commands do not execute and the local_exec for pg_queries.sh.tpl fails.

I wanted to check how to execute these psql queries in Prod as well?

1. In the local exec - should I ssh into an EC2 box and then run psql queries?
2. In the local exec, should I Create a ssh tunnel (ssh username@EC2_jump_box -N -L port:Aurora-cluster-endpoint:5432) and then run psql queries from local host?

Need some suggestions and help on terraform code to run these psql commands.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not use mysql or postgresql TF providers to manage the databases?

Comment: How will that help when I am running the tf code from my local system which does not have direct access to the Aurora DB.

Comment: I have used "remote-exec"  to run shell scripts, and I have have used "local-exec" to run an ansible remotely .    the ansible example should be in this github repo
https://github.com/ACloudGuru-Resources/content-deploying-to-aws-ansible-terraform

Comment: Organizations have tooling apps for CI/CD. It appears that you aren't using any of these. 
Íf you setup tooling servers which can talk to all environments, you will have likewise behavior. Otherwise, you hit these problems writing code to suit for a particular environment which is a bad idea!

Comment: @harshavmb -- I totally agree with you that having a CI/CD pipeline is the ideal solution to this however we are not there yet. Till we get the pipelines setup, we need some kinda solution. I actually used ssh tunneling (https://github.com/flaupretre/terraform-ssh-tunnel) and it worked for me.